# What type of bonsai tree is this

Tags: trees, bonsai

I will post also as a general question. 
Recently I received a bonsai tree. Can you help me identify what type is it? After few days I received it it seems weaker and with lots of yellow leaves. I need to find out the problem so for that is crucial to know the type of the bonsai I have.
On the pot I have a tag which gives me a general description of indoor bonsai like water regularly and keep out from direct sunlight but that's it. [image]

---

[image]

I will add also a close-up of the leaves. Hope it helps to identify it.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an indoor bonsai, it might be *Ficus benjamina* (or another *Ficus* species). You can check if it is a *Ficus* by pulling off one leaf and see if it bleeds white milky juice (which is not edible).

Indoor bonsai is difficult (outdoor bonsai is too btw, but indoor is even more), you might want to read more about it (search the web, there is much info out there). I had a few indoor bonsai trees in the past, but they didn't survive for long, like I said it is difficult. Especially heaters and radiators are killers.

The yellowing of leaves might be due to stress, *Ficus* is very sensitive for changes in the environment (changes in light, temperature, draft, etc.). *Ficus* can also lose all the leaves at once, if that happens try to see if it recovers (it usually does once or twice).

Comment: Well, I pulled a leaf but no milky juice.

Comment: Darn! Okay might be a Fukien tea, let's wait till it gets flowers.